# What's the real difference between a postdoc and a research fellow? (Which one is considered a 'better' experience?'

Tags: postdocs, job-search, job

As the title suggests, it's not clear to me the actual difference between a postdoc and research fellow, especially when looking at the typical academia road. I understand that (maybe?) there is a difference between how the two are funded, but which one that (naturally) shows more qualities that can be appreciated when looking for a job as a lecturer? Qualities like 'Independent researcher that can design and lead high quality research programs'.

Edit:
If it helps, I am talking specifically about the UK system.

Comment: There is often no difference, but practices vary.

Comment: A research fellow could, in theory, be a permanent position. A post-doc, probably not (hopefully not).

Comment: Which country? Nomenclature varies.

Comment: Thank you for answers, I am talking about academia in the UK.

Comment: My question was closed because it was a "duplicate" of the link mentionned. It does **NOT** answer my question, it's pretty generic and the answer is basically "it depends", and you can answer 100 questions with "it depends". As much as I appreciate people taking the time to help others, it's frustrating to see other users force what they think I want to know like that and it's always happening.

Comment: @U.User "It depends" is the correct answer.

Comment: I have edited the question and specified that it's UK related. So, at least, my question is not as generic as the link you've provided. You're free to read the accepted answer and compare it to all the comments/answers in that "duplicate" link.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist "It depends" is not the correct answer. The term fellow has a specific meaning in the UK system, even if some mis-use it.

Comment: @IanSudbery I see that the question has changed.

Comment: Wow.. Is it that hard to say sorry? The question was changed before you replied to my previous comment. You said "the question has changed" but you still haven't done anything about it.. At least vote to re-open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the UK system, there is a difference between a Postdoctoral research assistant (PDRA) and an independent fellow.

A PDRA is, in general, an employee of their PI. They often work on project designed by the PI, probably funded by a grant the PI obtained. While they are often given a lot of independence, they are, in the final analysis, hired to do a job.

In the case of an Independent Fellowship, such as the MRC's Career Development Fellowship, the BBSRC's David Philips fellowship or the Wellcome Trust's Sir Henry Dale fellowship, the postdoctoral researcher *is* the PI. They may work with a mentor or institutional sponsor, but they devise the research program, obtain the funding, hire any staff (although its less usual to have a research team beyond the fellow and maybe a technician), and have signing off rights on purchasing authority. A fellowship is the first step on the faculty ladder, and a much sought after one because a fellow is generally excused from any teaching responsibilities.

In biology, where authorship order matters, a PDRA would be expected to be the first author, a fellow the last or corresponding author on any publications.

Or another way of looking at it - for a PDRA the researcher applies to an advertised job vacancy and competes with others to win the position from the university. In contrast, universities will compete to host a fellow. Many universities will promise a fellow a permanent position after their fellowship ends if they agree to undertake their fellowship at that university (a so-called proleptic appointment).

In UK science at least, career paths look a bit like:

PhD (3-4 years) -> PDRA(2-3x, 2-3 years each) -> R&T Lecturer (5-10ish years) -> Senior Lecturer -> Prof

OR

PhD (3-4 years) -> PDRA(1 or 2x, 2-3 years each) -> Independent Research Fellow (R only, 5 years) -> R&T Lecturer/Senior Lecturer -> Prof.

OR

PhD (3-4 years) -> PDRA (3 years) -> Independent Research Fellowship (R only, 5 years) -> Senior Research Fellowship (R only, 3-5 years each, as long as you keep getting lucky) -> R&T Senior Lecturer/Prof.

You normally apply directly to the funder. You will need to nominate a host when you do, and will need a letter of support from the host institution, so you should approach potential hosts first.

One biological example of a research fellowship is the Sir Henry Dale fellowship:
https://wellcome.org/grant-funding/schemes/sir-henry-dale-fellowships.

Here is what Leeds University (not my uni) has to say about its support for people applying for fellowships: https://www.leeds.ac.uk/info/2000/research_and_innovation/699/fellowships

Comment: Thank you Ian for your answer. Apparently, I don't know a lot about careers in academia xD... a permanent research fellow position?? how is it different from the Lecturer -> Professor path? If it's not too much trouble, do you have some resources that I can read to know about this path (like how do you secure one?, how do you progress in your career since it's only a research job (unlike lecturers), advantages, etc?)

Comment: An independent fellowship isn't permeant, its time limited - but many universities tell you that you will get a permeant lectureship after you finish your fellowship. Fellowships are highly sought after positions, and most people get a lectureship without first having had a fellowship (I never had a fellowship). I'll add some details to the answer

Comment: Thank you very much Ian for your answers!!

Comment: @U.User I think this is certainly the correct answer in terms of colloquial usage of the two titles in the UK, though HR-assigned job titles may not always match this. Simplifying further: postdocs are funded on money awarded to someone else, whereas research fellows are funded using money they got for themselves. One does also occasionally see some variant of the 'Research Fellow' title used for academic staff who have a permanent job without any teaching role (though such positions are increasingly rare).

Comment: @avid Thank you. I did accept this answer earlier, I don't know what happened. I did get the basic difference between the two, here is what confuses me: I have seen advertised jobs (from universities) that look for "research fellows" with a given salary the same way I saw advertised postdoc jobs with the same salary. So, where does the difference in how funding is secured actually show? When I read these job descriptions, it looks like the difference is a background detail, it's still kind of confusing tbh

Comment: I can think of three situations where you might see this: 1) People in the UK, but who perhaps did there own PhDs and Postdocs in other places advertise for a position they call a fellowship, even though its not. 2) Sometimes universities will decide to fund some fellowships themselves (we've done this and called them "vice chancellors fellows"). For me the key difference between a postdoc and a fellow is who comes up with the research program more than who pays - the fellow themselves, or a senor faculty member.

Comment: @U.User Other possibilities are: (i) the HR department has decided to call postdocs (or perhaps just postdocs at the higher end of the pay-scale) "research fellows"; (ii) some universities are now posting "job ads" seeking people who wish to apply for external fellowships, i.e. there's no job unless you come with your own grant, and the ad is simply to encourage you to consider their university rather than another. I think Ian's (2) is the most common case, though.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth clarifying: things like 'Vice Chancellor's Fellowships' involve a pot of money from the university's central funds, with fellowships awarded to the best proposals with few restrictions on research area (sometimes the broad fields sought are prescribed). They are intended to allow the university to discover future superstars and new directions. This is distinct from a postdoc job in Dept X to work with Prof. Y on topic Z.

Comment: Mmm, interesting. When I emailed the professor for more information about a research fellow I saw, he said this ".. The researcher will sit with the project's coordinator.. He will have the chance to collaborate with X and Y from other universities", he also said "the researcher will need first to work on problem Z". So, it look like the university/Department got the funding, they have some sort of a research plan? But also not?. If the definitions vary by University, is it okay to email them directly?

Comment: I'm sure it's fine to ask. But ultimately it probably doesn't really matter what they call it: if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, me telling you it's a cow doesn't mean much...

Comment: Yes I know, even if the answer is a duck, it's still interesting to know about cows..

Comment: @avid I did think about suggesting the situation where institutions advertise for fellows, when what they mean is they will support you to apply for a fellowship, but left it out after the OP said "with a given salary the same way I saw advertised postdoc jobs with the *same salary*". A UKRI funded PDRA would almost certainly be paid less than an independent fellow.

Comment: @IanSudbery From the job postings that I've seen, the salary of both positions fall in the range £30,000 p.a. - £40,000 p.a to £45,000 p.a. This means that you can find a PDRA that can make more or the same as an independent fellow (This of course depends on the University, candidate, etc.). What I meant by that sentence is they fall in the same category (salary wise), since some institutions offer a higher range for PDRA positions..

Comment: In my field (Life sciences), postdocs are almost exclusively paid between national pay spine point 28 (£31,866) and point 39 (£44,045), while those hired as a PI on their own project would almost always be on spine point 37 (£41,526) to point 47 (£55,750). Be aware that 90% of hiring will take place at the lowest point of the range, unless you can demonstrate you are already earning more.

Comment: Interesting.. Can you please look at this link? (https://www.reddit.com/r/AskAcademiaUK/comments/k9pvhd/can_any_explain_whats_a_research_fellow_and/). I've asked around, and found that a research fellow is a researcher hired by a PI who **won** the fellowship. But someone in there raised a concerning comment, he mentioned that the PI (the owner of the project) can have complete control of the order of authors of a given paper regardless of who did what.

Comment: No. A someone hired by a PI who won the fellowship is not a real fellow. Did you look at the lists of fellowships I posted above. You'll see that in all cases the fellow is the PI.  I've never seen a fellowship that is applied for by a senior PI and then given to a junior. Sometimes the PI writes for a junior fellow (see e.g. Marie Curie early career fellowships). Soudns more like a normal postdoc that some has just called a fellowship. However, if you are appointed to a position funded by a PI, then yes, they do have full control over everything.

Comment: Yes, I have consulted the links when you posted them, thank you! I was more concerned about the comment that mentions that "the PI controls everything", I didn't know that! Everything is clear now. Thank you @IanSudbery !!

Answer (score 8):

**Q: It's not clear to me the actual difference between a postdoc and research fellow, especially when looking at the typical academia road.**

Correct. Often times there is not a difference.
Titles are institution specific (e.g., universities, national labs, funding agencies) and often sub-division within institutions (e.g., departments, even specific PIs based upon how they hire people with their institution's hiring mechanism).

Sometimes a title including *post-doc* or similar title (e.g., post-doctoral fellow) requires the person be within *X*-years of their terminal degree.
Conversely, as noted by others, *research fellows* or similar title can be permanent positions, be programs or even titles for experienced scientists, or be visiting programs for distinguished faculty and researchers from other places.
For example The American Association for the Advancement of Science (AAAS) has a [Fellowship Program](https://www.aaas.org/programs/science-technology-policy-fellowships/become-st-policy-fellow) for people (ranging from recent grads to tenured faculty) to gain experience applying science to policy.

You ask about demonstrating *Qualities like 'Independent researcher that can design and lead high quality research programs'*.
Rather than looking at title, demonstrate these qualities through outcomes.
For example, your CV might include (order the text based upon your CV's target such as a research or teaching school):

> **Position title**, Place Name, supervised by Dr. Smith (2019 -2020)
>
> Developed new widgets theory resulting *X* publications (depending upon your CV format, perhaps cross-ref here, e.g., Jones et al. 2019, Smith et al. 2020). Wrote grants for $XX,000 and managed the widget research project. Mentored *Y* peons. Presented results at *XYZ*. Developed and taught new course, Widget-ology. List other relevant outcomes to the position you're applying for.

Of course, list your grants, presentations, and publications in their own, respective sections of your CV.

Depending upon your subfield, the **Place Name** and the **PI** you worked under can be given a lot of weight or little weight compared to your outcomes (e.g., pubs, grants, technical skills).
Sometimes **Position Title** can carry weight, but these are usual for hard to obtain fellowships that are also captured in other parts of your CV (e.g., a US NSF Postdoc Fellowship that you obtains as the PI would also be listed under *Grants* on your CV).
Compared to a position's **nouns** (e.g., titles, places, PIs), actions usually carry more weight.
For example, **publishing** a first authored paper in *Science* or *Nature* would outweigh where you had your post-doc fellowship.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's pretty insightful!